# IF/ELSE Statement doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a ComboBox containing 5 values. An empty line, "Credit", "Debit", "Credit Settlement", and "Debit Settlement". I am trying to perform an error validation on it. If the user types anything in the combo box or if the selection of the empty string is made, I want to trigger an error. This is what I have now but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
    If cboTypeRes.Text.Trim = "" or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Debit" Or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Credit" Or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim = "Debit Settlement" Or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim = "Credit Settlement" Then
```

Comment: is `cboTypeRes.Trim` above just a typo? That should not compile.

Comment: ya, typo when I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the selected item is contained in the Items collection

```
if cboTypesRes.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("Error")
Else
    Dim curText = cboTypesRes.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim()
    if curText.Length = 0 OrElse Not cboTypesRes.Items.Contains(curText) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error")
    End If
End If
```

A little update:

The SelectedItem property could be Nothing when the user types the word directly or you user could types the word with a lower case first letter.
If you find these scenarios acceptable then you could try with this change

```
Dim curText = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(cboTypeRes.Text)
if curText.Length = 0 OrElse Not cbo.Items.Contains(curText) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Error")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
If cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Debit" AndAlso cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Credit" AndAlso cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Debit Settlement" AndAlso cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Credit Settlement" Then
    '...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cboTypeRes.SelectedText.Trim() ...
```

But is better to do this with `cboTypeRes.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Although there are easier ways to do data validation on a combobox, yours should work, it's just that your last 2 have `=` rather that `<>`.

Your statement should read:

```
If cboTypeRes.Text.Trim = "" or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Debit" Or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Credit" Or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Debit Settlement" Or cboTypeRes.Text.Trim <> "Credit Settlement" Then
```

Comment: No that doesn't work either. What other ways are you suggesting?